# The object with "Child of" constraint can't keep up with the target, when animation is played

Tags: animation

I am new to blender so maybe there is an easy solution to this but I didn't find anything that could've helped so far.

In a few words, the FPS arms are hitting the lock with the stone. The stone has "Child of" constraint with the target of right palm bone. If I drag the mouse frame by frame then it all looks ok. However when I play the animation, the stone is lagging behind the right hand. I assume its because this constraint has to process where the stone should be, every frame and can't keep up since the hit is a fast and big movement which takes 10 frames. But I don't know how to fix it.

This sounds like common problem to be honest, but I have no idea what can I try to fix it. I tried to play around in graph editor, to make it less visible but it didn't help.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It is a dependency loop.  Blender can't figure out what order you want things evaluated.  Open a console window and look for warnings.  You need to keep a clear hierarchy with any animation: if A depends on B, then B cannot ever depend on A, directly or indirectly.  Because of the loop, Blender is evaluating from the transform from the frame previous.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. There is little information on this topic and it isn't widely known for some reason: I found only one video on youtube about dependency cycles ahaha.  Would've taken me a while to find info if not your answer. But it was the problem and now it looks good, thanks.